# Selecting radio button in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some html document:

```
<ul class="ShippingProviderList">
<li>
<label id="shippingMethod">
    <div id="uniform-shippingCheck" class="radio">
     <span>
     <input type="radio" value="0">
     </span>
    </div>
    <span class="ShipperName">Shipping One</span>
    </label>
</li>

<li>
<label id="shippingMethod">
    <div id="uniform-shippingCheck" class="radio">
<span>
     <input id="shippingCheck" type="radio" value="2" name="selectedShippingMethod">
</span>
</div>
     <span class="ShipperName">Shipping Two</span>
</label>
</li>

<li>
<label id="shippingMethod">
<div id="uniform-shippingCheck" class="radio">
<span>
      <input id="shippingCheck" type="radio" value="1" name="selectedShippingMethod">
</span>
</div>
<span class="ShipperName">Shipping Three</span>

</label>
</li>
```

I would like to try to check if the string "Shipping One" is included in this document.
If "Shipping One" is included, I want to make  the radio button (here is value "0") is auto checked. 
But this value will be  changing dynamically ( "0" or "1" or "2" and so on). If values changed my code will be wrong.
How can I implement to be auto selected when value is changed too?

My javascript code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
var smethods = [];
    $('.ShippingProviderList .ShipperName').each(function() {
        var txt = $(this).html();
            smethods.push(txt);
    }); // end each

if($.inArray('Shipping One', smethods)==0){        
   $("input[type=radio][value='0']").prop("checked",true);
}else{
 $('.ShippingProviderList').prepend('<li><input type="radio" value="0"></li>');
}
```

});

Comment: what do you mean by "If values changed my code will be wrong?'

Comment: Sorry. My jquery code will encounter error. I mean this line.  $("input[type=radio][value='0']").prop("checked",true);

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for `-1` instead:

```
if($.inArray('Shipping One', smethods) === -1){        
    $("input[type=radio][value='0']").prop("checked",true);
}else{
    $('.ShippingProviderList').prepend('<li><input type="radio" value="0"></li>');
}
```

if `'Shipping One'` is in the array `'smethods'` then it will return the index of it whether it is available on any index, but if it is not in it then it will return `-1`.

A short example is below:

if anything found in array then `$.inArray()` returns the index of found object otherwise it will return `-1`.

```js
   var smethods = ['Shipping One', 'Shipping Two'];
   alert("Is 'Shipping One' in the array : " + $.inArray('Shipping One', smethods))
   alert("Is 'Shipping Two' in the array : " + $.inArray('Shipping Two', smethods))
   alert("Is 'Shipping Three' in the array : " + $.inArray('Shipping Three', smethods))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Checking the array is fine. The issue is how to make the radio button selected.

Answer (score 0):

Find the span by text, and then find the radio in its previous sibling:

```
$("span:contains('Shipping One')").prev().find('input').prop("checked",true);
```

Comment: Wow.. this is exactly the solution I'm searching. Appreciate your help Nadia Chibrikova. You save my life... :)

Comment: Always happy to save lives! You can accept the answer if it helped :)